# cordova 5 wp8 app build does not rotate

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, orientation, cordova-5.0.0

I use cordova 5.0.0 and build wp8 app.  When I rotate the phone, the app doesn't rotate.  It seems like some orientation setting or codes are needed.  Any ideas on how to do it?  For device, I use windows phone 8.1 on Nokia 822.

Comment: Having the same problem, worked with previous version of Cordova...have not found a solution so far

Comment: Put it in another way, let's say we generate a HelloWorld app.  What needs to be done so that the view rotates when we rotate a wp8 device.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova actually overwrites the orientation attributes defined in MainPage.xaml.  Codes in \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\wp8_parser.js actually remove settings if orientation is defined as 'default' in config.xml, place incorrect settings in MainPage.xaml for other values.
You need to write a hook to execute after prepare to overwrite the value cordova sets.